# rails validations error messages not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am trying to make a login in and sign up page but when i try to validate the email and password no error messages pop up I though they are supposed to pop up the the condition isn't met.

i have tried error messages through layouts view and helper but none work or are too confusing for me to understand.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new 
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.create(password: params[:password], email: params[:email], firstname: params[:firstname], lastname: params[:lastname])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
   redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

This is my users controller

This is my user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
        has_secure_password
        validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
        validates :password, length: { minimum: 4 }
        validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+ 
 [a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :message => "hollksd"(just for testing)
 end
```

This is my new user view

```
  <%= form_for @user do |form| %>
  <p> First name:<%= form.text_field :firstname %></p>
  <p>Last name:<%= form.text_field :lastname %></p>
    <p>Email:<%= form.email_field :email %></p>
      <p>Create password:<%= form.password_field :password %></p>
  <%= form.submit %>
<%end%>
```

if anyone could help it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your html elements are not associated to User model please try to use form_for tag instead somewhat like below

```
<%= form_for @user do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= form.text_field :last_name %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<%end%>
```

Also please use `render :new` instead of `redirect_to root_path`

Comment: helpful tip but it didn't seem to fix my problem

Comment: could you pls share what are the issues you facing now

Comment: I am not facing any errors just that when i try to validate a user email or password no error is shown @Manoj Menon

Comment: are you still using form_tag in views?

Comment: yes i am im change change my question to display it

Comment: pls add error messages display in view inside  form_for block                               <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

Comment: also pls share your rails application log in question when you submit the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198809/discussion-between-manoj-menon-and-code-prodigy).

Answer (score 1):

You you need to update your `create` action to something like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(password: params[:password], email: params[:email], firstname: params[:firstname], lastname: params[:lastname])

  if @user.save
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Why render `new` when it fail to save? Because we need to let know know that this form is not valid, and by rendering new with the `@user` object, you get access to `@user.errors` where you can do whatever you like (formally form will render a red border and error message next to input).